# how to choose a particular dotnet core sdk when publishing dotnet app

Tags: .net, .net-core, publish, dotnet-cli

I have an application targeting dotnet 5.0.* which I publish using the command line. I've used Visual Studio 2019 with dotnet 5.0.* SDK installed and publishing worked fine on that.

But, I recently installed [Visual Studio 2022 Preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/), and tried running `dotnet publish` command, it failed due to the preview sdk. See the console error message I'm getting below.

[image: error message on publish, image link]

I have searched most of MSDN docs on how to specify dotnet version while publishing a dotnet app, but could not find a solution.

I am using the powershell scripts below:

```
$version  =  "6.12.0"
$product  =  "CrystalERP"
$project  =  "I:\CrystalRelease\crystal.erp\crystal.pos.cafe\Crystal.Pos.Cafe.csproj"
$output  =  "I:\App"
$dotnet  =  "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"
$runtimes  = @(
"linux-x64"
)
# clear previous releases

Remove-Item "$output\App*"  -Recurse -Confirm:$true
$runtimes  |  %{
&  $dotnet publish $project  -c release   -r $_  -o ("{0}\{1}"  -f $output,"App")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a common version to be used across all your application development to be consistent with dependency and tools.

**Command:**

```
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version <installed sdk versions of .NET>
```

It will create **"global.json"** file.

To check what versions are installed ( in case you are not aware )
use -

```
dotnet sdk check
```

**output:**
[image]

After getting version details you can set which one to use based on your requirements

**e.g.**

```
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 6.0.306
```

**Generated file location:**

```
"C:\Users\username\global.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

Building/publishing is a feature of the SDK.

You can use `dotnet --list` SDKs to see all the SDKs installed on your machine.

Then you should use `global.json` to specify the SDK that should be used to build your application.

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "5.0.100",
  }
}
```

See [`global.json` docs for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x).